# paypal ipn not sending mail or processing and not connected to database?

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn

im on localhost so i am using ngrok.com for sandbox. but my problem is my ipn.php i think, is not connected to my database? it also not sending me mail. on cmd at ngrok i can see datas on http requests for my ipn.php so i think its processed? but data is not inserting to my database? i alse have other code which sending mail and i can receive all sendmail and php ini is configured and paypal ipn is configured.
please see the codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<?php

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "awsus 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "awsus 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("argie_tamera", $con);

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req.= "&$key=$value";
}

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($req)."\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";



$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com',80,$err_num,$err_str,30);
//$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// or use port 443 for an SSL connection
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR Failed to connect
// You can optionally send an email to let you know of the problem
// or add other error handling.
 $myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "HTTP ERROR \n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "$errstr\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
//email
$mail_From = "From: glenpaps23@gmail.com";
$mail_To = $email;
$mail_Subject = "HTTP ERROR";
$mail_Body = $errstr; //error string from fsockopen
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
} else {
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "after else\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh); 
fputs($fp, $header . $req."\r\n\r\n");
while (!feof($fp)) {
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "after while\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
$res = fgets($fp, 1024);

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Get res value baby\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$res\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);

if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $item_colour = $_POST['custom'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "after verified baby\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$item_name\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$item_number\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "payment status: $payment_status\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);           
    $stringData = "receiver email: $receiver_email\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "amount: $payment_amount\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);           
    $stringData = "currency: $payment_currency\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);

    $amount_they_should_have_paid = $payment_amount; //lookup_price($item_name);

    // receiver_email is same as your account email //check they payed what they   should have // and its the correct currency
    /*if (($payment_status == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email ==     "argiep_1323161081_biz@gmail.com") && 
    ($payment_amount == $amount_they_should_have_paid) && 
    ($payment_currency == "PHP") && 
    (!txn_id_used_before($txn_id))) { //txn_id isn't same as previous to stop  duplicate payments. You will need to write a function to do this check.*/

     if (($payment_status == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email ==   "glenpaps23@gmail.com") && 
    ($payment_amount == $amount_they_should_have_paid) && 
    ($payment_currency == "PHP") ) { //txn_id isn't same as previous to stop    duplicate payments. You will need to write a function to do this check.

        // everything is ok
        // you will probably want to do some processing here such as logging the  purchase in a database etc
        $sql = "INSERT INTO payment_notification (item_name, item_number, status,  amount, currency, txn_id, payer_email) 
        VALUES 
          ('$item_name','$item_number','$payment_status',$payment_amount,'$payment_currency','$txn_id ','$payer_email')";
        mysql_query($sql);

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Completed baby\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$item_name\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$item_number\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "$sql\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);           
    fclose($fh);

        //        uncomment this section during development to receive an email to     indicate whats happened
        $mail_To = "glenpaps23@gmail.com";
        $mail_Subject = "completed status received from paypal";
        $mail_Body = "completed: $item_number  $txn_id";
        mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body);
    } else {
        //
        // paypal replied with something other than completed or one of the security checks failed.
        // you might want to do some extra processing here
        //
        //in this application we only accept a status of "Completed" and treat all others as failure. You may want to handle the other possibilities differently
        //payment_status can be one of the following
        //Canceled_Reversal: A reversal has been canceled. For example, you won a dispute with the customer, and the funds for
        //                           Completed the transaction that was reversed have been returned to you.
        //Completed:            The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance.
        //Denied:                 You denied the payment. This happens only if the payment was previously pending because of possible
        //                            reasons described for the PendingReason element.
        //Expired:                 This authorization has expired and cannot be captured.
        //Failed:                   The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was made from your customerâ€™s bank account.
        //Pending:                The payment is pending. See pending_reason for more information.
        //Refunded:              You refunded the payment.
        //Reversed:              A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of reversal. The funds have been removed from
        //                          your account balance and returned to the buyer. The reason for the
        //                           reversal is specified in the ReasonCode element.
        //Processed:            A payment has been accepted.
        //Voided:                 This authorization has been voided.
        //
        //
        // we will send an email to say that something went wrong
        $mail_To = "glenpaps23@gmail.com";
        $mail_Subject = "PayPal IPN status not completed or security check fail";
        //
        //you can put whatever debug info you want in the email
        //
        $mail_Body = "Something wrong. \n\nThe transaction ID number is: $txn_id \n\n Payment status = $payment_status \n\n Payment amount = $payment_amount";
        mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body);
        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = "status baby:\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        $stringData = "$mail_Body\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }
  } else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = "INVALID baby:\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        $stringData = "$mail_Body\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);        
    //
    // Paypal didnt like what we sent. If you start getting these after system was working ok in the past, check if Paypal has altered its IPN format
    //
    $mail_To = "glenpaps23@gmail.com";
    $mail_Subject = "PayPal - Invalid IPN ";
    $mail_Body = "We have had an INVALID response. \n\nThe transaction ID number is:  $txn_id \n\n username = $username";
    mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body);
}
} //end of while
fclose($fp);
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "gn close gd...\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 fclose($fh);   
}
?>
```

what am i missing? i dont know why my code dont work, i dont know why.

Comment: you must debug you code by just commenting all the status check condition

Comment: what? i dont understand..

Comment: I mean to say that while using sandbox account you must to comment all the status like if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { so remove those and check it once and then tell me what happen

Comment: removed it but still nothing happen?

Comment: try to use @mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body); insted of mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body);

Comment: still no data inserted to database :( no email :(